# C++ Template Basics - Function Accept Sub Class or Super

Tags: c++, templates

Say you have a sub class B which inherits from super class A.  You want a function that can accept either A or B.

```
template <typename T>
void someFunc(T* pObj, bool someOtherArg)
{
    pObj->AnInheritMethod();
    if (pObj->IsASub())
    {
       pObj->ANonInhertMethod();
    }
}
```

When I compile this (Visual Studio 6) I get:

```
error C2065: 'pObj' : undeclared identifier
```

Am I way off base here?

Comment: First of all, you should declare the return type for `someFunc`. Secondly, creating the `A` version of this method (`someFunc<A>`) will fail since `pObj` will not define the methods of the derived class (`AnInheritMethod` in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function template for this; the following will do just fine:

```
void someFunc(A* pObj)
{
    pObj->AnInheritMethod();
    if (B* pObjAsB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pObj))
    {
        pObjAsB->ANonInheritMethod();
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer to use your `IsASub()` member function instead of `dynamic_cast`:

```
void someFunc(A* pObj)
{
    pObj->AnInheritMethod();
    if (pObj->IsASub())
    {
        B* pObjAsB = static_cast<B*>(pObj);
        pObjAsB->ANonInheritMethod();
    }
}
```

Aside from the missing return type, I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code in your example; I don't have Visual C++ 6 installed to check.

Comment: While this answer is completely correct, the OP should note that the need to do this (check for a subclass and then perform a cast in order to call a non-inherited function) is nearly always indicative of poor object-oriented design.

Comment: @Tyler: Perhaps.  There are certain scenarios where casts make for simpler, cleaner code, and I think those scenarios are more common than many hard-line OOers admit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need templates for that, that is a free behaviour courtesy of polymorphism.

Edit: also if you write something like:

```
if (pObj->IsASub())
```

then there's maybe something wrong in your design. The method is supposed to work for any type in the derivation chain.

Comment: @vulkanio, thanks, the IsASub was just an oversimplification.  The super class a method to determine which sub class it can be cast too.

Comment: @Mark: There's one in the language, it's dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a question that is completely unrelated to the code and error that you included.

In order to have a function take an `A` or a class derived from `A`, all it needs to do is take a pointer or reference to `A`, e.g.

```
someFunc(A* pObj, bool someOtherArg);
```

or

```
someFunc(A& obj, bool someOtherArg);
```

It will work by virtue of inheritance. That's kind of the whole point of deriving classes from each other. The way you have written it with templates, it will work with *any* class that defines the three methods you use, whether or not it derives from `A`.

Now the error you posted is unrelated to this question but is bizarre. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, but Visual Studio 6 is an ancient compiler; it's twelve years old and does not fully support modern ISO standard C++. This error may be an artifact of a sub-standard templating implementation in the compiler.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right, I think I somehow corrupted the project.  Now that I've modified the code as described above, I get linker errors.  Ughh, screw you ancient tools my company can't seem to let go of!!!  At least I'm learning.